# Mapbox/Android/Java - Add marker

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I have been working with maps on android as a developer for quite a while, now  I have to intgrate MapBox to an exisitng app that is only Java, no Kotlin, and I find absolutely no way to add a marker to a Mapbox map!

To be honest this is ridiculous, it should not take more than a couple of minutes. Sorry for my rant.

All documentation is only for Kotlin, any attempt to migrate it to Java and you find that most methods/classes are not available.

This is my import:

```
   implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.12.0'
```

And this is the map being instanciated:

```
    mapView = mView.findViewById(R.id.fpmb_mapView);
    mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);
    mapView.getMapboxMap().setCamera(new CameraOptions.Builder().center(Point.fromLngLat(-56, -34)).zoom(8.0).build());
```

Any help in adding a Marker would be much appreciated.

EDIT 1: Following the kotlin example does work, it requires tweaking..., but it works: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/add-one-marker-symbol/ or https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/default-point-annotation/